# Finding the minimum value of the expression $xy(x+y)^2 + yz(y+z)^2 + zx(z+x)^2$

Tags: polynomials, optimization, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

From R. D. Sharma's *Objective Mathematics*,

> Given that $x + y + z = 1$, ($x,y,z$ are positive real numbers) find the minimum value of $$A = xy(x+y)^2 + yz(y+z)^2 + zx(z+x)^2$$

---

**My attempt:**
By A.M.-G.M. inequality,

$$\begin{align}
  (x+y)^2 &\geq  4(xy) \\
  (y+z)^2 &\geq  4(yz) \\
  (z+x)^2 &\geq  4(zx)
\end{align}$$

By multiplying by $xy$, $yz$, $zx$ in these equations respectively, gives

$$\begin{align}
 xy(x+y)^2 &\geq 4(xy)^2 \\
 yz(y+z)^2 &\geq 4(yz)^2 \\
 zx(z+x)^2 &\geq 4(zx)^2 \\
\end{align}$$

Adding these equations, we get

$$  A \geq 4[(xy)^2 + (yz)^2 + (zx)^2] $$

Using AM GM inequality once again on RHS, we get

$$ A \geq 12(xyz)^{\tfrac43}$$

However, provided answer key says that minimum value is $4xyz$. I do not want a solution but only wants to know that is  something wrong in my procedure? Why?

*EDIT* : This question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question . However, readers will believe that my problem is different if they re-read the paragraph just above .

Comment: @Rodrigo This problem is from my practice textbook .

Comment: @Sourav Yes because products of two positive number is also positive and preserve the sign of inequality

Comment: @Sourav Sorry , I will edit it.

Comment: If the question is to find the minimum value of $A$, how can the answer be an expression in $x,y,z$? I'm afraid that the intended answer doesn't make sense, the way the question is phrased.

Comment: @YiFan Yes, I agree. I treated it as different inequality

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $x,y,z&gt;0$ and $x+y+z=1\;,$ Then prove that $xy(x+y)^2+yz(y+z)^2+zx(z+x)^2\geq 4xyz$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657914/if-x-y-z0-and-xyz-1-then-prove-that-xyxy2yzyz2zxzx2-geq)

Comment: @SouravGhosh No , the question text is same however the problem is different. I am asking for why my proof yeilded a different answer , instead of asking for a solution . However , if the community feels , it can close the question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that,

If $x,y\to 0$ with $z\to 1$, we have

$$\inf \left\{xy(x+y)^2 + yz(y+z)^2 + zx(z+x)^2\mid x+y+z=1 \wedge x>0\wedge y>0\wedge z>0\right\}=0$$

As for obtaining the inequality $A≥4xyz$, you can easily obtain this result using the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality):

$$(xy(x+y)^2 + yz(y+z)^2 + zx(z+x)^2)\left(\frac 1{xy}+\frac 1{yz}+\frac 1{xz}\right)≥4(x+y+z)^2=4$$

$$\frac A{xyz}≥4\implies A≥4xyz.$$

But, note that $xyz$ is not a constant. Therefore, $4xyz$ is not a "minimum". We only proved that,

$$xy(x+y)^2 + yz(y+z)^2 + zx(z+x)^2≥4xyz$$

The inequality you want to prove.

Comment: I don't know much about Cauchy Schwars . Anyway thanks for a solution . But also , Please adress that why my procedure was wrong

Comment: I see you edited the question

Comment: Yes but only that x,y,z are positive numbers .

Comment: Does this mean that there is no certain minimum ? We will get different minimum values for different x,y,z?

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments.You can use [this](https://approach0.xyz/search/)

Comment: @SouravGhosh $A≥4xyz$ is not a dupe.

Comment: @User see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1657914/977780 exactly same question. This question will be removed latter, I believe.

Comment: @SouravGhosh It is possible. But note that, this is not a solid argument for deletion. Because, answers are different and these **can be** useful for site.

Answer (score 1):

You have not used the condition of $x+y+z=1$. Since when $x=y=z=1/3$ the equality holds, your answer is the same with the $4xyz$ answer. So the textbook answer is flawed. you can get a numerical minimum value of $4/27$.

Comment: Numerical minimum value is 0 at $x,y\approx0,z\approx1$

Comment: The minimum value is not $\dfrac{4}{7}$, and it should be $0$ as Suzu Hirose pointed out earlier. The correct question should be to find the maximum rather than the minimum.

Comment: @SuzuHirose No , it is given that x,y and z are positive . They can't be zero . Do you mean minimum value tends to zero but never equals to zero ?

Comment: @Get_Maths $\approx$ means "approximately", so $x, y=0.0000000001$, $z=1-x-y\approx1$ or something then $A\approx 0$. It never gets to exactly zero of course but it goes as close as you like, certainly smaller than $4/7$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Does this mean that problem is wrong ? I am so confused with inequalities . I have found similar results with other problems too i.e. getting different expressions than book using correct methods. Please tell What should I do?

Comment: @WangYeFei If minimun value is close to zero , then does this mean that AM-GM inequality failed ?

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments.You can use [this](https://approach0.xyz/search/)